# Blender rendering differences when using CPU vs GPU

Tags: rendering

[image: GPU and CPU renders of exact same blender file.]

If you look closely at the two pictures, you’ll see the GPU render has ridge lines going through every object from half the width over to the end. The blender files used were exactly the same. Any ideas as to what’s happening?

Comment: CPU and GPU renders should be the same in theory, in practice though, differences are to be expected

Comment: But this seems like a substantial difference. I don’t think the GPU rendering is usable.

Comment: It might be a bug or driver issue, hard to tell without knowing anything about your hardware or system

Comment: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980M

Comment: Try to share the file, to let others compare with your results